# Can users sign-in with Google after registering with a plain email form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-signin, account

Our website offers [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) as a way to create an account and subsequently sign in. We also offer the option to register and sign in for an account using a 'traditional' email form.

Is there a way for our system to allow users to use Google Sign-In if they originally created their account using the email form?

i.e. Can system recognise that `account email = google mail` and allow the user to sign in with Google and bypass having to input their password – even though they did not originally create their account with Sign-In with Google

We are trying to create an experience where if the user forgot that they created their account with an email, they can still easily and seamlessly sign in by using Google Sign-In.

Comment: Sure. All Google does is confirm that the user has authenticated themselves to Google. What your app does after that (create an account, start a session, don’t start a session, etc.) is up to you.